# Issue with deleting my own question

Tags: support, self-delete

I consider [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293297/how-to-master-abstraction) badly shaped, so I flagged it to kindly ask for delete.

It was declined with reason *None of the answers are upvoted, you can delete it yourself.* However, I can't: a red box appears saying *Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.*

So I flagged it again, but it is still active since 15.2. I'd like to have it deleted, but it's no big deal: I'm just curious when can I delete my question.

Comment: Strange. You should indeed be able to delete it.

Comment: I upvoted one of the comments. Could this be the reason?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the condition is actually "upvoted answer *or more than one answer*".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [an answer on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), you cannot delete your question that has multiple answers.

> You can't delete any question that:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

Currently, your question has 3 answers (there are no votes on any of them).

Comment: Ahhh, so that's it.